# StackOverflowError на jetty

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jetty

Пытаюсь демонстрировать у себя на экране .jsp страничку. В ответ на мой код вылетает: `Error for /java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Что делать?

**Код "инициализатора":**

```
package com.example;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class JettyJSP extends Thread{
public void run() {
    Server server = new Server(1600);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new PageServlet1()),"/*");
    try {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Код Сервлета:**

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PageServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String message = "Hello World";
        request.setAttribute("message", message); // This will be available as ${message}
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/webapp/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Код index.jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2370960</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <p>Message: ${message}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: стектрейс-то покажите

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все просто. `java.lang.StackOverflowError` - это бесконечная рекурсия. Как такое могло произойти? Посмотрим.

```
 context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new PageServlet1()),"/*");
```

Вы создаете сервлет `PageServlet1`, который будет отрабатывать по **всем** url-ам, начинающимся с `/`. Внутри сервлета вы вызываете форвард на `"/webapp/index.jsp`, но этот url само собой попадает под маску `/*`, что приводит нас в `PageServlet1`. И так пока не обрушится стек.

Самое простое, что можно сделать, это убрать `*` из маски url-а:

```
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new PageServlet1()),"/");
```

Кроме того, я не вижу у вас инициализации поддержки JSP. Возможно, вы захотите добавить, что-то вроде этого (не забыв настроить):

```
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder("jsp", JettyJspServlet.class), "*.jsp");
```

Более конкретно сложно что-то посоветовать, так как не очевидно, пытаетесь ли вы раздавать jsp вручную или в составе war. В любом случае не помешает посмотреть на официальный пример: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp