# Error 404 с jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, веб-сервер, jetty

Прошлый вопрос, где есть код всего этого добра ([тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493577/stackoverflowerror-%D0%BD%D0%B0-jetty/493619#493619)).
web.xml не использую, через код все должно работать (вроде).

Сейчас проблема состоит в том, что jetty не видит мой `index.jsp`, хотя он лежит в той самой папке webapp.

Я и в `src` пробовал ее затолкать, и просто в проект, но ответом мне была ошибка.
В чем причина?

Answer (score 1):

А раньше видел? Попробуйте путь к jsp прописать без указания директивы webapp:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```