# Как программно отобразить jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jetty

Использую jetty. Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести jsp без использования web.xml, просто через код.
Каким образом это сделать?

Пытался использовать код:  `request.getRequestDispatcher("webapp/index.jsp").forward(request, resp);`

Но выбивает `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: пока это похоже на дубликат этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493577 и этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493988/

Comment: вы посмотрели пример отсюда: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp ?

Comment: @Nofate, я же их и задавал. Посмотрел-посмотрел.

Comment: Я знаю, что задавали вы. Я к тому и клоню, что может быть не стоит плодить одинаковые вопросы,  разобраться в одном? Пример по ссылке собирали/запускали/работает? Пробовали перенести решение оттуда?

Comment: @Nofate, для начала, про то, что не видит index.jsp, ответ дан не правильный. Я сейчас вроде разобрался с ним, но данный вопрос отличается от двух других. Для начала, тем, что он просто про строку кода. Гугл совсем ничего не дал, там в большинстве примеров через web.xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> для начала, про то, что не видит index.jsp, ответ дан не правильный.

Если вы про мой ответ, то не стоило его отмечать правильным, если он неправильный (что неверно). Нужно было добавить подробности в исходный вопрос.

> Для начала, тем, что он просто про строку кода.

Со строкой кода проблем нет. Я еще в первый раз написал вам, что обработка JSP требует дополнительной инициализации. JSP - это же не просто шаблон для HTML, который вы отдадите в response. Это исходник для компиляции отдельного класса сервлета, который в свою очередь уже и будет формировать итоговый HTML и отдавать его пользователю.

Anyway... Демо, которое я предлагал вам посмотреть более чем работоспособное. На адаптацию под ваши условия ушло минут 20.

Смотрим.

---

Структура папок, стандартная для maven-а:

```
src
- main
| - java
| | - demo
| |   - App.java
| |   - PageServlet1.java
| - resources
|   - webapp
|     - index.jsp
pom.xml
```

---

index.jsp - без изменений

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SO question 2370960</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Message: ${message}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

PageServlet1.java

```java
public class PageServlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String message = "Hello World";
        request.setAttribute("message", message); // This will be available as ${message}
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

---

App.java

```java
package demo;

import org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager;
import org.apache.tomcat.SimpleInstanceManager;
import org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JettyJasperInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        Server server = new Server(1600);
        // указываем базовый путь к директории webapp в ресурсах
        URI baseUri = App.class.getResource("/webapp").toURI();

        // отключаем использование компилятора Eclipse JDT, но для запуска потребуется JDK, а не JRE
        System.setProperty("org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199", "false");

        JettyJasperInitializer sci = new JettyJasperInitializer();
        ContainerInitializer initializer = new ContainerInitializer(sci, null);
        List<ContainerInitializer> initializers = new ArrayList<ContainerInitializer>();
        initializers.add(initializer);

        // Инициализация контекста
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        // временная директория требуется для компиляции JSP
        context.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", getScratchDir());
        context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
                ".*/[^/]*servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$|.*/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-.*\\.jar$|.*/.*taglibs.*\\.jar$");
        context.setResourceBase(baseUri.toASCIIString());
        context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers", initializers);
        context.setAttribute(InstanceManager.class.getName(), new SimpleInstanceManager());

        // по спецификации JSP стандартный загрузчик классов не годится, используем URLClassLoader
        context.setClassLoader(new URLClassLoader(new URL[0], App.class.getClassLoader()));

        // Наконец, создаем сервлет для обработки JSP. Он обязан называться "jsp" 
        ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder("jsp", JettyJspServlet.class);
        holderJsp.setInitOrder(0);
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("logVerbosityLevel", "DEBUG");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("fork", "false");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "false");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerTargetVM", "1.7");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerSourceVM", "1.7");
        holderJsp.setInitParameter("keepgenerated", "true");
        context.addServlet(holderJsp, "*.jsp");

        // Также должен существовать сервлет с именем "default". Это будет ваш PageServlet1
        ServletHolder holderDefault = new ServletHolder("default", PageServlet1.class);
        holderDefault.setInitParameter("resourceBase", baseUri.toASCIIString());
        holderDefault.setInitParameter("dirAllowed", "true");
        context.addServlet(holderDefault, "/");

        // Поехали
        server.setHandler(context);

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Вспомогательный метод, создающий временную директорию. Хорошо бы ее удалять после использования.
    private static File getScratchDir() throws IOException {
        File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File scratchDir = new File(tempDir.toString(), "embedded-jetty-jsp");

        if (!scratchDir.exists())
        {
            if (!scratchDir.mkdirs())
            {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create scratch directory: " + scratchDir);
            }
        }
        return scratchDir;
    }
}
```

---

В CLASSPATH должны лежать все необходимые библиотеки. Если вы используете maven, вот зависимости:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @Nofate Все грамотно разложено по полкам. Наблюдаю эту ситуацию, поражаюсь Вашему терпению. Человечище! Плюс в карму. :)

Comment: @Nofate, извиняюсь. Просто выдавало ошибку. Сейчас все функционирует.
Огромное вам спасибо за потраченное время, я наконец-то разобрался.